# EntityObject 5.x and Self Tracking Entities 5.x

Tags: entity-framework

Does anyone know the if/when/where behind the self-tracking entities template for the latest version of EF? Our team would like to move forward to be able to take advantage of the performance improvements that the EF team has documented, but we haven't been able to find any reference to the new T4 templates for self-tracking entities, which we are dependent upon.

We've tried firing up the old template, but the framework has changed too much.

There's a thread on MSDN about it, but it has not been updated in a while. (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/4993d0bf-94e8-4d14-aff1-3458b4ad467f/#889cc5f1-e267-448a-ae82-e3d705b7dfa5)

Thanks.

Comment: I would not be surprised if neither of those templates would be produced. `EntityObject` is mostly deprecated and self-tracking entities were replaced by WCF Data Services.

Comment: Now I see you are asking for 5.x templates - those even cannot exist because EF 5.x is only `DbContext`. It doesn't support `EntityObject` entities and STEs for DbContext never existed (at least officially).

Comment: STE exists. Got word from MS today that they are finishing up the licensing aspects of it and will release the template later this week.

Answer (score 1):

You can download it from [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a3ac10a5-9365-4096-bb58-d9a1ba71db8f?SRC=VSIDE), they are available now.